# How to cite a book with no editor but different authors for every chapter?

Tags: citations

I want to cite from [this](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-05328-7) book. It has explicitly marked different authors for the chapters, but there are no editors given on the front pages. Is this then regarded as a monography rather than a miscellany/anthology or do I use all authors as editors?

Comment: I think you cite the particular chapters you refer to, each with its authors.

Comment: So I use the authors as editors of the book?

Comment: @manuel459 The front matter doesn't make any mention of an editor, so it seems more appropriate to consider them all as authors of the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say something like

> Joos, Erich,  *title of appropriate chapter* ,  in
> *Decoherence and the Appearance of a Classical World in Quantum Theory* , Springer, etc,  Chapter zz   pp. xx-yy.

in whatever format best matches the bibliography style of the journal.

Comment: I've used this format for a chapter in a book with no known editors. If I wanted to cite the whole book rather than a particular chapter, I'd just delete the part "Joos ... chapter, in" from Ethan's example.

Answer (score 1):

@Ethan Bolker gives the right answer, and the only thing that one should add is to remind you of the purpose of a citation: It isn't an elaborate exercise in testing whether you can follow a specific syntax (this is for all of you APA folks out there! :-) ), but it is a way to help your readers find related literature. If you provide the citation in a way that makes it easy for readers to find what you are pointing to, then you've succeeded, and the example by Ethan Bolker achieves this.